# Messages not translating into different language in STS thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dto, notnull

In spring boot, for validating field of thymeleaf form, I am having multiple languages, so
when I translate the form into different, my validation message is not translating its show in
English.
I have different property file for each language.
Since my form translate into different language, if I change the language, only the issue is
with the validation message displaying on screen.

```
  @NotEmpty(message = "{city.notblank}")
  @Size(min = 1, max=100)
  protected String city = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Spring Boot to use the message sources for the error messages. Add this bean to your application:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
    return bean;
}
```